# how to always upload an unique image name to aws S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I ensure that I always upload a unique filename to aws S3?
Current solution:  image name with timestamp.

Comment: Too broad but [GUID](https://www.guidgenerator.com/)

Comment: I want to programmatically create an unique Number.

Comment: I know, so search how to create a GUID programmatically

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Enable Version when you create the bucket.

Comment: This will prevent inadvertent deletion-by-overwrite, but does not solve the question that was asked -- how to avoid object key collisions.